# Initialize instance with integer constant 0 but no other constant value or integer variable

Tags: c++

I want to define a class whose instances can be constructed, implicitly constructed, or assigned from an integer constant zero, but not from any other numeric constant, and not from a variable with integer type (even if its value happens to be zero at runtime).  It should also be copy-constructible from other instances of the same class.  Use of C++11 features is okay as long as they're supported (in the appropriate mode) by both g++ 4.6 and MSVC 2010.

Concretely, given

```
class X { /* ... */ };
void fn(X);
```

these should all compile:

```
X a(0);
X b = 0;
X c; c = 0;
X d = a;
X e; e = a;
fn(0);
```

but these should not:

```
X f(1);
X g = 1;
X h; h = 1;
fn(1);

int ii = 23;
X a(ii);
X j = ii;
X k; k = ii;
fn(ii);
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
class X {
public:
   X() {} 
   constexpr X(int v) { static_assert(v == 0, "must be initialized from zero"); }
};
```

⟶

```
test.cc: In constructor ‘constexpr X::X(int)’:
test.cc:3:29: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
test.cc:3:29: error: ‘v’ is not a constant expression
```

Comment: Okay. What's the use case?

Comment: Why not use a default constructor instead?

Comment: The use case is long and complicated and not really all that relevant.  Suffice to say that X has some similarities with a number (the full class defines some manifest constants and some arithmetic operators) but the only point of overlap with numeric literals is zero.  Default construction is fine and all, but in some cases (like passing the argument of `fn`) it is more natural to write a zero.

Comment: This would be a really nice thing to have, but I doubt it is possible. The closest you might get is probably a solution with C++11 user-defined literals (which I think aren't fully supported by any compiler yet), but it's doubtful if that would be really any better than a solution with some unique `class nullVectorX{};` object.

Comment: I don't understand... remove the default constructor and throw an exception if it isn't 0. Why does that not work?

Comment: @0A0D I want mis-initialization to be a compile error, not a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If require C++0x, you could use `std::nullptr_t`:

```
class X
{
public:
  X () { }
  X (std::nullptr_t) { }
  void operator= (std::nullptr_t) { }
};
```

Well, with the downside that `X` becomes initializable with `nullptr` too, of course.

Comment: This might be acceptable if no one can come up with anything better.

Comment: There's no particular reason to use `nullptr_t`, you can just as well define a `zero` class of its own that can't be casted to anything else. Using `nullptr` when the object is not pointer-like would strongly violate the ᴘʀɪɴᴄɪᴘʟᴇ ᴏꜰ ʟᴇᴀꜱᴛ ꜱᴜʀᴘʀɪꜱᴇ.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If I understand what you're proposing correctly, it would not allow people to write "`X(0)`", which is a requirement.  `nullptr_t` has the unusual property of being implicitly convertible from an integer constant with value 0, but from no other integer constant; this happens to be exactly what I want.

Comment: @Zack: Indeed, it wouldn't allow that. I didn't expect your idea was actually using `X(0)`, since I don't think it would work reliable: calling a `f(std::nullptr_t);` with `f(0)` is not standard-conformant, is it? `f(NULL)` is guaranteed to work, but the `NULL` macro is not required to be simply `0`. May not be relevant right now, but as `nullptr` is the recommended keyword now I'd expect compilers to produce at least warning messages when doing such function calls in the future.

Comment: Last sentence in C++11 (well, N3337) 4.10p1: "A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t."  So yes, calling `f(std::nullptr_t)` as `f(0)` is conforming.  I certainly hope no such warnings ever materialize; it is my strongly held opinion that the correct way to write a null pointer is either `0`, or in the *very rare* cases where that doesn't work, `(TYPE *)0` for some concrete TYPE.  (Put another way, I approve of the addition of `nullptr_t`, but not `nullptr` itself.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace (v == 0) with a constant expression...

Something like

```
constexpr bool is_zero_construct(size_t number)
{
  return number == 0;
}

constexpr X(int v) { static_assert(is_zero_construct(v), "must be initialized from zero"); }
```

Comment: Doesn't help: `v` itself is still not a constexpr, so it objects to the call to `is_zero_construct`.  Changing `int v` to `int constexpr v` gets me "error: a parameter cannot be declared constexpr".

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the fact that only 0 can be implicitly converted to a pointer:

```
struct X {
  X();
  X(void*);
};
```

This fulfills your requirements, but of course allows initialization with a pointer as well.

Comment: Accidental initialization with a pointer is much less likely in context than accidental initialization with a nonzero integer constant, but I would still prefer to rule it out if possible.